# Require_once is not executed on ajax call

Tags: php, ajax, require-once

This is my 'index.php' file (part of it):

```
<?php

// Require every .php file inside "phpClasses" folder
foreach (glob("phpScripts/*.php") as $filename) {
require_once $filename;
}

// Create the $db object
$db = Database::obtain(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_DATABASE); 

// Connect to the database
$db->connect();

// Instantiate the "language" and "databaseQuery" classes
$lang = new language();     
$dbQuery = new databaseQuery();     

// Detect if the laguage has changed from the user and apply the new "current language"
if(isset($_GET["change_lang"])) {
    $change_lang = $_GET["change_lang"];
    $cur_lang = $change_lang;
} else {
    $cur_lang = $lang->getCurLang();
}
?>
<head>
...
</head>
<body>        
    <div id="cur_content" class="temp_content" data-tempPos="0">
    <?php 
        include 'pages/home.php'; 
    ?>
    </div>  <!-- #cur_content -->
</body>
```

Inside #cur_content I inject 'blog.php' via ajax call:

'blog.php':

```
<div id="blog_main_content" class="temp_content">
    <?php
        include "blog_list.php";
    ?>
</div>
```

..and inside it, I include 'blog_list.php':

```
foreach (glob("phpScripts/*.php") as $filename) {
    require_once $filename;
}

// Create the $db object
$db = Database::obtain(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_DATABASE); 

// Connect to the database
$db->connect();

$dbQuery = new databaseQuery();     

// Get the language from loader.php
$cur_lang = "'".$_SESSION['language']."'";

$dbQuery->getArticleList($cur_lang);

 ?>
```

Inside #blog_main_content div, I inject 'articleLoader.php' via ajax call and works fine.
'blog_list.php' is displayed just fine for the first time. 
When user returns to 'blog_list.php' via ajax call, I get the following error:

Fatal error: Class 'Database' not found in        C:\wamp\www\kapantzakis_2.14\pages\blog_list.php on line 8

I think that php does not execute the require_once in 'blg_list.php' when ajax calls this file.

I don't know if I explain well.

Thanks for any help!

edit#1

Ajax call:

```
// Perform the ajax call
        function getAjaxPage(method, content, currentOffset) {

            var temp_content = $('.temp_content');                      
                var temp_content_last = temp_content.filter(':last');

            var blog_main_content = $('#blog_main_content');                    
                var blog_main_content_first = blog_main_content.filter(':first');

                // Insert the html data in to the first or last div depending on the movement of the page
                if (method == 'next') {
                    var insert_div = temp_content_last;
                } else if (method == 'prev') {
                    var insert_div = blog_main_content_first;
                }

                // Get article or the article list
                if (content == 'article') {
                    var page = 'articleLoader.php';
                } else if (content == 'article_list') {
                    var page = 'pages/blog_list.php';                       
                }
                /*
                var lang = getCurLang();
                var data = 'lang=' + lang + '&art_id=' + art_id;*/

                var tags_wrapper = $('#tags_wrapper');

            $.ajax({
                url: page,  
                type: "GET",    
                /*data: data,*/
                cache: false,
                success: function (html) {                          
                    insert_div.html(html)
                        .queue(function() {
                            var return_to_list = $('#return_to_list');                              
                            return_to_list.attr('data-offsetTop', currentOffset);   
                            returnTopOffset();
                            if (content == 'article') {
                                tags_wrapper.fadeIn(800);
                            } else if (content == 'article_list') {
                                tags_wrapper.hide();
                            }                               
                            $(this).dequeue();
                        });
                }       
            });
            return $(this);
        }
```

Comment: Er, where is the AJAX call? I only see a PHP inclusion.

Comment: I've tried require_once("$filename"); but the same thing happens

Comment: I don't think this is a great idea, but have you tried `include("$filename");` as well? If you did, what was the result?

Comment: Ignacio, I've tried that, but it is not solved! The thing is that it works when it is included via 'blog.php', but when 'blog_list.php' is called via ajax, php does not execute the 'require_once'

Comment: why you don't use require or include??

Comment: It's awkward to see that it doesn't load, try to check what errors it is giving since that's the easiest way to find out. Check error.log which should be inside your apache2 folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your folder structure looks like this:

```
kapantzakis_2.14/
  articleLoader.php
  blog.php
  blog_list.php
  index.php
  pages/
    home.php
  phpScripts/
    Database.php
```

Your AJAX-Call requests `pages/blog_list.php` directly, but in your question-text it seems like `blog_list.php` is located in your root directory (`kapantzakis_2.14`).

The error you get ([...]`'Database' not found in C:\wamp\www\kapantzakis_2.14\pages\blog_list.php`[...]) shows the `blog_list.php` is located in the `pages`-folder instead. Your `glob`-call cannot find a directory called `phpScripts` in the `pages`-Folder, so the `required_once` calls never get executed.

Comment: Thanks robbi! That seems to be the problem!

Answer (score 0):

```
// add this line on the top of your script
ob_start();


// add this line on the bottom of your script
$errors = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$fopen = fopen('errors.txt', 'w+');
fwrite($fopen, $errors);
fclose($fopen);
```

and you can get all errors